# picture az map with zoom in c# form application

Tags: c#

I have picture that I should use it as map in my C# form application.

Is there any way that I can put some points or buttons on this picture that when user click on it some things happens.
A thing that is important for me is that I want user can zoom on the map. But if the user zoom on map buttons wouldn't move.
I want locate some click-able points in the map that can be zoomed and moved too.
Thanks.